# Select items based on two constraints keeping the computational effort low

Tags: c#, performance, sorting

I have a list of items and I want to select all items that are valid for a given date. Each item contains a unique identifier, some info and a start and end date. The data structure of these items need to be created only once, but it contains 100.000 items and there are a lot of requests. I was thinking that the data structure is sorted descending by e.g. "endDate" and then I search (using binary search) for the first "endDate" that is not valid anymore, meaning the endDate is before the given date - for example I have a given date of 29.07.2022, then I would know I could discard:

```
endDate
-------------
30.07.2022 
28.07.2022 <-
26.07.2022 <-
23.07.2022 <-
```

That would keep the computational effort low. But then I have to sort the data again for startDate. Is there a better way to do this? What data structure would you recommand here?

```
var itemList = new List<Item>();

class Item
{
     public string id {get; set;}
     public string startDate { get; set; }
     public string endDate { get; set; }
     public string someInfo { get; set; }  
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify all the queries you want to make against the data? So far you've mentioned searching for the first end data beyond a specified date. What query do you need for the start dates?

Comment: Also how is this data used? Is it updated frequently? How often is it updated compared to how often it is queried? The answer to these questions may influence the best solution.

Comment: In general, if have the basic set of data containing all items which can be sorted initially but it should remain the same later. Only queries. There are no items added or removed, I just need for each request (given date) all valid items (given date between start and end date). But my goal is to avoid going through each item seperately and checking if it is valid (O(n)). The algorithm was just a proposal in hope to get something more efficient.

Comment: The answer I posted should work in `O(Log(N))` to find the items beyond/before a specified start/end date. Then iterating over those items will be `O(P)` where P is the number of items found. That last cannot be avoided of course - you will be operating on P items no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that you have frequent insertions and deletions as well as frequent lookups.

If you want to look things up using two different sorts (for performance reasons), you'll need to maintain two different sorted containers.

For this, you can use [`SortedSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-6.0). This gives you `O(Log(N))` lookups, insertions and deletions.

(It's not actually necessary for this specific code example for your class to implement `IEquatable<Item>`, since it won't be used for `SortedSet<T>`. However, it's good practice to add this. Note that if you use a `record` type, `IEquatable<Item>` will be automatically implemented for you. I have omitted the implementation of `IEquatable<Item>` from this answer, but be aware that if you change the code to use a hashing container you MUST implement `IEquatable<Item>` and `GetHashCode()` correctly for the class.)

You will need to ensure that all the properties used for identity and sorting are immutable - because otherwise if you change those properties of an item that is currently stored in a sorted container, it will break.

So your `Item` class would have to look something like this:

```
public sealed class Item
{
    public Item(string id, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string someInfo)
    {
        Id        = id;
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate   = endDate;
        SomeInfo  = someInfo;
    }

    public string   Id        { get; } // Used for identity therefore must be immutable.
    public DateTime StartDate { get; } // Used for sorting therefore must be immutable.
    public DateTime EndDate   { get; } // Used for sorting therefore must be immutable.
    public string   SomeInfo  { get; set; } // Not used for sorting or identity, so can be mutable.
}
```

Now you need a way of comparing `Item` objects by start date and by end date, for use with the two differently-sorted `SortedSet<T>` collections. We can do this by writing a small class that implements `IComparer<Item>`:

```
sealed class ItemComparer : IComparer<Item>
{
    public ItemComparer(bool compareStart)
    {
        _compareStart = compareStart;
    }

    public int Compare(Item? x, Item? y)
    {
        int byDate = _compareStart 
            ? x!.StartDate.CompareTo(y!.StartDate) 
            : x!.EndDate  .CompareTo(y!.EndDate);

        if (byDate != 0)
            return byDate;

        return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
    }

    readonly bool _compareStart;
}
```

The constructor for this class accepts a `bool` which defines whether it will sort by `StartDate` or by `EndDate`.

Now you can write a class that encapsulates the two differently-sorted `SortedSet<T>` collections and provides higher-level methods to add, remove and search for items. This class will also contain a nested implementation of the `ItemComparer` class above, since this is merely an implementation detail that doesn't need to be exposed:

```
public sealed class ItemStore
{
    public bool Add(Item item)
    {
        _byEnd.Add(item);
        return _byStart.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Remove(Item item)
    {
        _byEnd.Remove(item);
        return _byStart.Remove(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _byStart.Clear(); 
        _byEnd  .Clear();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsAfterEndDate(DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1);  // For AFTER the end date.

        var start = new Item("", date, date, "");
        var end   = new Item("", DateTime.MaxValue, DateTime.MaxValue, "");

        return _byEnd.GetViewBetween(start, end);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsBeforeEndDate(DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(-1); // For BEFORE the start date.

        var start = new Item("", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "");
        var end   = new Item("", date,              date,              "");

        return _byEnd.GetViewBetween(start, end);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsAfterStartDate(DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(1); // For AFTER the start date.

        var start = new Item("", date,              date,              "");
        var end   = new Item("", DateTime.MaxValue, DateTime.MaxValue, "");

        return _byStart.GetViewBetween(start, end);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> ItemsBeforeStartDate(DateTime date)
    {
        date = date.AddDays(-1); // For BEFORE the start date.

        var start = new Item("", DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, "");
        var end   = new Item("", date,              date,              "");

        return _byStart.GetViewBetween(start, end);
    }

    sealed class ItemComparer : IComparer<Item>
    {
        public ItemComparer(bool compareStart)
        {
            _compareStart = compareStart;
        }

        public int Compare(Item? x, Item? y)
        {
            int byDate = _compareStart 
                ? x!.StartDate.CompareTo(y!.StartDate) 
                : x!.EndDate  .CompareTo(y!.EndDate);

            if (byDate != 0)
                return byDate;

            return x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
        }

        readonly bool _compareStart;
    }

    readonly SortedSet<Item> _byStart = new(_byStartComparer);
    readonly SortedSet<Item> _byEnd   = new(_byEndComparer);

    static readonly IComparer<Item> _byStartComparer = new ItemComparer(compareStart: true);
    static readonly IComparer<Item> _byEndComparer   = new ItemComparer(compareStart: false);
}
```

You should be able to see how to add further methods to this class, if you need to add more functionality.

You can test this class with code such as this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var items = new ItemStore();

    items.Add(new Item("1", DateTime.Parse("2022-07-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01"), "1"));
    items.Add(new Item("2", DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01"), "2"));
    items.Add(new Item("3", DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-10-01"), "3"));
    items.Add(new Item("4", DateTime.Parse("2022-10-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-11-01"), "4"));

    items.Add(new Item("1.1", DateTime.Parse("2022-07-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01"), "1.1"));
    items.Add(new Item("2.1", DateTime.Parse("2022-08-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01"), "2.1"));
    items.Add(new Item("3.1", DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-10-01"), "3.1"));
    items.Add(new Item("4.1", DateTime.Parse("2022-10-01"), DateTime.Parse("2022-11-01"), "4.1"));

    Console.WriteLine("Items with start date before 2022-09-01");

    foreach (var item in items.ItemsBeforeStartDate(DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nItems with end date after 2022-09-01");

    foreach (var item in items.ItemsAfterEndDate(DateTime.Parse("2022-09-01")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `SortedSet<T>` is a hashing container? My understanding is that this collection is implemented as a binary tree, not as a hash table.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You're correct! I'll  edit the answer.

Comment: Since you pass a comparer to both `SortedSet<T>`s, I think that overriding the `Equals` is redundant. Also redundant seems to be the `GetHashCode` override.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If your class implements `IEquatable<T>` then it is [advised to implement `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0) too.

Comment: That's true, but why implement the `IEquatable<T>` in the first place?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, it's true that it's not required for this example, but IMO once you start putting things into sorted or hashed containers, it's best to make sure that things will behave properly even if you change container types. Failure to do that risks some quite nasty and hard-to-find errors down the line. This would affect things like `BinarySearch()`, `List<T>.Contains()`, and obviously all of the hashing containers. I think It's good practice.

Comment: Hmm, AFAIK implementing the `IEquatable<T>` has no effect when putting something in a sorted container. It only has effect with hashed containers. The effect is that it changes the equality semantics of the class. By default the semantics is reference equality, and I can't see why the default semantics aren't suitable for the `Item` class and need to be customized. Also I consider a flaw to include in an answer good practices that are not required for solving the core problem, without being explicit about it. People might be misled into believing that the good practice is part of the solution.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You are entitled to your opinion! I'll edit the answer to make it clearer that this is not needed. Also note that the `record` type does automatically implement `IEnumerable<T>` for you (Microsoft evidently thought it important enough to add this to `record` support).